# Hive - When adding a new column to a table I get: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Invalid column reference

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to overwrite a table by merging other 3 tables. In the following way:

1. I will take all columns from the table1
2. I will take just two columns from table2
3. I will add a new columns based on the values of a column in table 3

The three tables: table1, table2 and table3 have as key id

This is the query I am trying (So far I am trying it without the `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE final_table`, just with the SELECT to see the results that would be inserted in the table)

```
--INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE final_table 
select 
        t1.*,
        t2.field1,
        t2.field2,
        CASE WHEN ( t3.indicator = 'F' OR 
                    t3.indicator = 'O' 
                    ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS new_field3
from 
table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON (t1.id = t2.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
ON (t1.id = t3.id);
```

But in the `CASE WHEN` I am getting the following error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10002]: Line 7:17 Invalid column reference 'new_field3'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a semantic error, but try writing the query as:

```
select t1.*, t2.field1, t2.field2,
       (case when t3.indicator in ('F', 'O') then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as new_field3
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left outer join
     table3 t3
     on t1.id = t2.id;  -- ???
```

Most of the changes are cosmetic.  `IN` is recommended instead of lists of `OR` expressions -- if only because it is easier to write and to read.

More importantly, the `join` conditions on `table3` do not include `table3`.

Neither of these -- to the best of my knowledge -- would generate a semantic exception.  However, the second means the query is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: thanks, you start replying before I completed my edit in that part you pointed out: "More importantly, the join conditions on table3 do not include table3".